# Как в Access создать процедуру или функцию?

Tags: access, sql

Здравствуйте. Как можно в Microsoft Access 2007/2010 создать процедуру или функцию, возвращающую числовое значение?  
Или если нельзя создать sql процедуры или функции, то как создать собственную функцию на VBA, чтобы ее можно было использовать в sql запросах внутри Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно создать функцию VBA. Ее надо создавать таким образом (для Access 2007):

На вкладке "Создание" выбрать "Модуль". Откроется окно VBA. И там можно создавать функции:

```
Public Function mfd(f As Long)
    ' Возвращает сама себя '
    mfd = f
End Function
```

Теперь эту функцию можно применять в построении sql-запросов в Access.

А на сколько я понял, хранимые функ sql-функции и процедуры, создавать и хранить в Access нельзя.

Comment: @ХэшКод, Примите ответ.

Comment: @Антон Мухин Сейчас можно принимать свой ответ на вопрос: для этого надо подождать два дня - появится галочка.

Answer (score 0):

Обращение к OlDbSchemaTable вернёт как процедуры все запросы с параметрами. Запросы без параметров трактуются как представления.

Comment: А где Вы такое нашли? Приведите простой пример, пожалуйста. А то что-то в документации такого не нахожу.

Comment: Даже и близко не вижу ничего, связанного с этим. Вы Microsoft Access имеете ввиду?

Comment: OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable